# Reaction between phenol and nitrous acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, phenols, nitro-compounds

My question is about the products formed when phenol reacts with nitrous acid. I googled it and reached [this PubChem paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12598009) ([DOI: 10.1016/S0045-6535(02)00857-3](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0045-6535(02)00857-3)), which states:

> It was found that phenol reacts with nitrous acid to produce cyanide ions. Cyanide ion generation is attributed to the conversion of phenol to nitrosophenol through the well-known nitrosation reaction, and decomposition of benzoquinonoxim to form cyanide and aliphatic compound.

Is this correct? If not, then what is the actual reaction?

Comment: The reference is behind a paywall, I assume you bought it or otherwise gained access.  Do tell what they did (procedure, conditions) to find said cyanide ions, then we can make an objective evaluation.

Comment: @Nilay that gets us to the quinoxime,but then what? Assuming the quinoxime forms, it could ultimately release cyanide if either a water molecule or the oxime hydroxyl group attacks adjacent to the oxime carbon. 
If this occurs, it breaks both the carbocyclic ring and the N-O bond from the oxime.  But, is such a reaction plausible?  We need access to the paper to know, maybe?

Comment: @OscarLanzi, I simply typed phenol with nitrous acid on Google and tht was the first link shown by Google..

Comment: I found out that this mechanism is only valid in wastewater treatment from all the research papers I gathered and not discussed anything about cyanide formation in general analytic chemistry. It only says that $\ce{NO+}$ is the electrophile in this reaction and nothing about cyanide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What the reference says**

The reference gives only following figure to support their theory. A weakness of this mechanism is requiring a high energy intermediate like sp2-carbocation.

[image: Cyanide from phenol]

**An alternative proposal**

This alternative avoids high-energy intermediates and thus appears more likely:

[image]